# Showing sum of diagonal shifted Toeplitz matrix is singular

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am attempting to prove a linear algebra fact but I don't know how:

Let $x(n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and define vector of length $L$ as $X(K) = [x(L+K-1),x(L+K-1),....x(K)]^T$ The goal is to prove that when $K<L$

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{K} X(i)X(i)^T $$ Is a singular matrix

This is easy to show when K = 1 but I have no idea how to extend it to the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the sum of $K$ rank-1 matrices. Hence its rank is at most $K$. Hence the matrix cannot have full rank and it is singular.

Comment: Ok this reasoning makes sense, it's a reasonable statement but I don't think I have ever seen it proved before - is it an easy proof?

Comment: Ok I just found a proof rank is subadditive, thanks - this was really easy in retrospect, I just completely ignored it and focused on the toepltiz structure.